Is $y = (\log x)^u$ faster than $y = x$ for any $u$?
If $(\log x)^u\over x$ converges to a constant as $x \rightarrow \infty$, then the set $S$ of possible values of $u$ is
(A)$[-1,1]$
(B)$(-\infty,1]$
(C)$(-\infty,\infty)$
(D)None of the above
Here's my approach to solve:
I use L'Hôpital's repeatedly,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} {(\log x)^u\over x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} {u(\log x)^{u-1}\over x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} {u(u-1)(\log x)^{u-2}\over x}= ...... = \lim_{x\to \infty} {u(u-1)(u-2)...(u-(n-1))(\log x)^{u-n}\over x}=0$$ where, $n \geq u$
And thus option (C) should be correct as it works for $\forall u\in\Bbb R$
Is this approach right? Please comment any mistakes or improvements.

Derivative of $(\log x)^u$ is $u(\log x)^{u-1}/x$, not just $u(\log x)^{u-1}$.

@ultralegend5385 thats exactly what i did. i differentiated both numerator and denominator. Denominator' differentiataion is 1 and i wrote the 1/x of $u(\log x)^{u-1}/x$ in the denominator

Sorry, my bad. In that case it looks fine to me.

For set inclusion use $\in$ (\in) and to denote the real numbers use $\mathbb R$ (\mathbb{R}).

The proof looks fine, although it isn't very elegant in my opinion. Here I suggest an alternative resolution. Let:
$$L = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log x)^u}x$$
And:
$$\tilde L = L^{1/u}$$
We shall now separate the cases $u<0$, $u=0$ and $u>0$. If $u<0$, the limit is obviously $0$, as it's a form $[1/\infty]$. If $u=0$, the limit also trivially equals $0$, as $(\log x)^u = 1$ (for $x\ne1$, but $x\to\infty$, so this is no problem).
The case $u>0$ also isn't difficult. Of course, the following equality holds:
$$\tilde L = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/u}}$$
And this limit notoriously equals $0$ for all $u$, which can be easily verified using l'Hôpital's rule. Thus, $\tilde L=0$ and $L=\tilde L^u=0$.

For an alternative approach, take another logarithm to get $u \log\log(x) - \log(x)$, which goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$ for any value of $u$.
